# Can pedestrians enter a marked crosswalk at an angle or cross the street without entering the marked path AND still have right-of-way?

Tags: traffic, driving

Scenario:

- There is a controlled crosswalk.
- The walking sign is on.

Rather than cross the street via the path, you cross adjacent to it OR you cross at an angle initially and enter the path.

If a car is driving through the crosswalk at this time, do you have right-of-way?

Comment: Jurisdiction matters here, which country you're discussing?

Comment: USA.This happened to me actually. I was crossing the street at an angle towards the crosswalk, so I wasn't on the crosswalk. The signal said walk, and a car drove through the crosswalk and bumped into me.

Comment: The regulation of road traffic is a matter of state law in the United States.  In what state did this occur?

Comment: In Ohio, the crosswalk does not only include the area marked as such: http://codes.ohio.gov/orc/4511.  Depending on where you actually walked, you may have been in the crosswalk all along.

Answer (score 1):

> i was hit the other day when crossing. the walk signal was on, but i was crossing at an angle towards the crosswalk. the car bumped into me slowly so the driver would have seen me. was i wrong?

It will depend on the exact state law - but in New Jersey for example assuming you weren't actually *on* the crosswalk when you were hit you would be [jaywalking](https://www.nj.gov/oag/hts/pedestrian.html) and would be required to yield right-of-way to the vehicle (emphasis mine):

> Always cross at corners, **within** marked crosswalks where available.
>
> If crossing in other locations, **yield the right of way to vehicles**. Failure to obey the law carries a $54 fine (court costs additional; C.39:4-32, 33)

Comment: this was ohio. i read that when the signal say walk, i can walk across the roadway. didnt see a distinction about within the lines or not

Comment: @confusedpanda1 Nope - in Ohio I believe the same applies, if you are outside a marked crosswalk you have to yield to drivers not the other way around.

Comment: @confusedpanda1 the law almost certainly says you must cross in a crosswalk when you get the walk signal.  You were likely jaywalking.

Comment: @Andy but a jaywalking pedestrian is not a free target for the driver of a motor vehicle.  Even if the pedestrian is crossing illegally, the driver has an obligation to "exercise due care" to avoid hitting the pedestrian (at least in New York).

Comment: @phoog Sorry, but where did I say they were free targets?  Whether or not the driver has an obligation not to hit a pedestrian does not make the jaywalkers actions legal.  Depending on the local law, they may also be considered at fault when determining liabilities because they broke the law.

Comment: @Andy you didn't say that, but one might infer it.  The question is not explicit, but a reasonable question to be inferred is "did the driver do anything wrong?"  The answer to that question is probably *yes.*  And I suspect that most systems have jurisprudence about how far a pedestrian must be from the crosswalk to be considered not in it.  New York, at least, defines "crosswalk" in part as "any part of the road at an intersection between the curbs...or, if there are no curbs, between the edges of the road," which will include some pavement that is outside the markings.

Comment: Ohio has a similar definition: http://codes.ohio.gov/orc/4511

Comment: @phoog What people might or  might not infer is not my problem.  "The question is not explicit, but a reasonable question to be inferred is "did the driver do anything wrong?" The answer to that question is probably yes"  That depends very much on the circumstances.  If the pedistrian entered the road at such a point where the driver had almost no warning, its reasonable to answer "did the driver do anything wrong' with "no."  As far as NY goes, yes, the question depends very much on jurisdiction..

Comment: @phoog Of course if I'm on a jury you'd have a hard time convincing me of some imaginary boundary that expends beyond the explicit markings of a marked crosswalk.   I've never seen any jaywalking law mention anything like that.

Comment: @Andy but I cited two laws that *do* have such a provision; that's 100% of the laws I checked.  It's a small sample, but can you find one that doesn't?

Comment: @phoog I read the Ohio code, and could not find anything about extending the boundaries of **marked** crosswalks.  The only imaginary boundaries I saw were for unmarked cross walks.  Care to site the **specific** part of the Ohio code that backs your argument on marked crosswalks?

Comment: @Andy the definition at [4511.01(LL)(1)](http://codes.ohio.gov/orc/4511) applies regardless of whether there is also a marked crosswalk.

Comment: @phoog No, that defines a crosswalk without markings, LL2 describes an explicitly marked crosswalk.  A crosswalk is either 1 or 2, not both.

Comment: @phoog notice .13A3a says "marked **or** unmarked associated crosswalk," further backing the interpretation of a marked vs unmarked crosswalk, defined separately.

Comment: @Andy any place that meets the definition of 1 or 2 is a crosswalk regardless of whether there is another place meeting the definition in the same intersection. If someone is outside the marked pedestrian crossing but is within the prolongation of the property lines and curb lines then that person is within the crosswalk.

Comment: @phoog Sorry your interpretation is incorrect. The markings override the boundries defined for an unmarked crosswalk.  If they did not what exactly is the point of bothering with markings at all?  Note that the text i quoted precludes the possibility of your interpretation.

Comment: @Andy how do you imagine that the quote precludes my interpretation?  That someone may cross within any marked or unmarked crosswalk does not say that an unmarked crosswalk cannot be adjacent to a marked one.  If the distance from the property line to the curb is 10 feet, and there's a 6-foot-wide marked crosswalk aligned on one edge with the curb, then there is a 4-foot-wide unmarked crosswalk adjacent to the other edge.

Comment: @phoog For one, its not reasonable; why bother marking only part of the crosswalk, when the purpose of marking it is presumably to clearly indicate where it is?  Second the wording i quoted; that wording is appropriate if a crosswalk can be either marked **or** unmarked.. not partially marked.  Otherwise the wording would be "marked or unmarked portion of the associated crosswalk", since its unreasonable to think there are marked and unmarked crosswalks directly adjacent to each other.  Your interpretation is unreasonable, so I think the burden of proof is now on you to site case law citing

Comment: @phoog your position.

Comment: @Andy I don't see any reason to think that your position is more reasonable than mine.  Anyway, my argument is about what the law says on its face. But can you point to any case law where someone who was within 6 feet of a marked crosswalk was held not to be in a crosswalk?  If so, was the question of whether the person was within an unmarked crosswalk adjacent to a marked one considered?  I've read quite a few cases over the last couple of days, but they all involved people who were either indisputably outside any crosswalk or in a marked crosswalk.

Comment: @phoog Your interpretation is unreasonable because it then leaves the boundaries of a marked crosswalk unclear, which defeats the purpose of marking a crosswalk to begin with.  There'd be no reason to mark crosswalks at intersections because we already have the definition in LL1 to know the boundaries.   Why waste the money?  Why spend money only marking a portion of the crosswalk, why not just mark the ENTIRE crosswalk if the city is making the effort to mark it at all?  Plus, considers marked crosswalks NOT at intersections.  You know have the same markings that are interpreted differently..

Comment: @phoog .. which leads to confusion.  I know of no other traffic control markings/signs that have different meaning depending on the context they're used in.

Comment: @Andy it doesn't leave the boundaries of a marked crosswalk at all unclear. It only holds that there is (possibly) an unmarked crosswalk adjacent to the marked one. And this only matters if courts are ruling against pedestrians who are only a few feet outside of marked crosswalks. I've found no evidence of that actually happening. To the extent that the purpose of a crosswalk is to draw drivers' attention to the presence of the crosswalk, the precision implied by your interpretation is unnecessary or even counterproductive. It's about road safety, not about enforcing rules as in a ball game.

Comment: @Andy if the legislature wanted to exclude my interpretation, they could have added the words "in the absence of lines or other markings on the surface" to (LL)(1).  But they didn't.  And the US already has plenty of traffic signs and signals that mean different things in different contexts.  Unmarked crosswalks are also inherently ambiguous, because most motorists will have no idea whatsoever where the extension of the property line into the roadway precisely is.

Comment: @phoog It does make it unclear, and the fact that we're debating this proves it.  Again you provide no ration justification for there to be an umarked crosswalk immediately adjacent to a marked one; it does not make sense, and you can't seem to justify it.   Marking the crosswalk is not just for drivers, its for pedestrians to know where they may cross as well.  Pedestrians have their own role to play in road safety.  And these rules are important when determining liability, which is the point of the question.

Comment: @phoog They don't need to, because they are creating distinct definitions for "crosswalk" which each stand on their own.  And if they wanted your definition, they could use the wording "marked or unmarked portion of the associated crosswalk" in the actual codes which appear later.

Comment: @Andy no, the boundaries of the marked crosswalk are perfectly clear: it is the area delineated by the markings. The unclear boundaries are those of the adjacent unmarked crosswalk, just as the boundaries of *every* unmarked crosswalk are unclear, because they are unmarked. The justification for this interpretation is the plain language of the statute.  That each definition "stands on its own" does not prevent them from standing together. And why would they need to say "marked or unmarked portion of the associated crosswalk" when they can just say "crosswalk"?

Comment: @phoog That is my point; your argument is that only a portion of the cross walk is marked, which confuses things, which is why the markings are the only boundary where they are present.  You're right, the law could just say crosswalk, but they don't, they, in several places, say "marked **or** unmarked associated crosswalk."  Since that language is used, it clarifies that LL1 and LL2 are mutually exclusive kinds of crosswalks.

Comment: @Andy that simply doesn't follow.  In fact, by my interpretation, it would be incumbent on the authority marking a crosswalk to insure that the marking covers the entire legal crosswalk, and in fact the [Ohio MUTCD](https://www.google.com/maps/@39.1610664,-84.3991342,50m/data=!3m1!1e3) does just that, starting on page 430.  It also says "At non-intersection locations, crosswalk markings legally establish the crosswalk." This clearly implies that markings at an intersection do not legally establish the crosswalk. An improperly marked crosswalk could therefore be partially outside the markings.

Comment: @phoog Sure it does.  The authority making the crosswalk markings might have other things they are taking into account, such as a buffer zone between a stop line and the crosswalk they are marking.  My interpretation allows for that, yours does not.  Non-intersection markings are irrelevant to the OP, and of course non-intersection markings cannot possible include LL1, so the only way to have a crosswalk NOT at intersection is via LL2.  That they discuss non-intersection markings is irrelevant, because you can't have an unmarked non-intersection crosswalk at all.

Comment: @phoog Let me make this 100% clear for you; the ONLY reason LL1 exists is to save money so that localities don't have to mark crosswalks at every single intersection in their jurisdiction.  If money were not a factor, I can't fathom **any** valid reason not to only have LL2 on the books.  Obviously marking every single crosswalk everywhere would be preferred because it eliminates **all** ambiguity, but its cost-prohibitive, so LL1 exists.

Comment: @phoog As a local example, there was an intersection in my city which only had 3 of the four corners linked with crosswalk markings.  My interpretation of this is that crossing was NOT allowed at the unmarked portion.  Otherwise, why would the city clearly have spent money to mark the other three but not the remaining one?  Last year, the city **DID** in-fact spend the money to add curb cutouts and mark the final side of the intersection to allow crossing.

Comment: @Andy regarding your local example, your interpretation does not agree with the Ohio court of appeals. Here's a case in which someone crossed "in the unmarked crosswalk" despite the other three crossings at an intersection having marked crosswalks: https://www.sconet.state.oh.us/rod/docs/pdf/8/2010/2010-ohio-6360.pdf ("he opted to cross eight lanes of traffic *in an unmarked crosswalk,* despite three marked crosswalks with signals available for him to utilize"; emphasis added).

Comment: @phoog I never said my local example applied to Ohio.  Be good job ignoring the other points I made which are the most reasonable line of thinking in Ohio, and probably the entire US which have similar laws.

Comment: @Andy I haven't ignored them.  The problem is that none of what you've written describes how courts actually interpret statutory texts.  They might consider a "reasonable line of thinking" to resolve a conflict in an ambiguous or self-contradictory law, but the law here is neither.  If there's no contradiction in the plain meaning of the law, courts do not infer additional conditions simply because they are "reasonable." You've also conveniently ignored the MUTCD's implication that the legal boundaries of a crosswalk at an intersection are independent of the markings.

Comment: @phoog "The problem is that none of what you've written describes how courts actually interpret statutory texts. "  Really? Because you've yet to post ANY case law that says the boundaries of the crosswalk may be a combination of the definitions in LL1 & 2 for any jurisdiction in the US.... which is what we've been going back and forth on.  That was your assertion, and you've yet to provide anything backing it up.  That someone used an unmarked crosswalk when OTHER marked crosswalks exist doesn't support your "extended boundries" claim.

Comment: @Andy and indeed you've posted no case law that supports your position. The best I could find was the Ohio MUTCD, which is good enough for me: the people whose job it is to make the rules for marking crosswalks in Ohio agree with my interpretation of the law. But I did read quite a few court opinions, none of which had anything to say on your position or mine, so either nobody has ever challenged the interpretation of this text (perhaps because it's obvious, or for any of several other reasons) or it was decided before they started putting decisions online.

Comment: @phoog Your position is the unreasonable one.  It makes much more sense that unmarked and marked crosswalks are two distinct types, and the markings create explicit boundaries.   You've never even given a single logical reason why the unmarked boundaries would continue to apply when there are explicit markings, you've never addressed the wording in later parts of the law i quoted... the burden of proof is on your position, not mine.   Its time to put up or shut up.

Comment: @Andy your saying that my position is unreasonable doesn't make it so.  What makes sense is that statutory texts mean what they say and say what they mean.  I do not need to give a logical reason, because the statute says it, plain as day. I *did* address the wording in the later part of the law by noting that your conclusion from that wording does not follow logically. That section is completely irrelevant because it makes sense under both interpretations. It therefore does not favor either one.  But the Ohio DOT *does* agree with my interpretation. Do you really imagine that they're wrong?

Comment: @phoog And you thinking its reasonable doesn't make it so, the wording in the law DOES make my stance logically follow (they take the time point out that it applies to both kinds of crosswalks, not some weird hybrid), and the DOT doesn't back your position at all, it is only talking about a place where a crosswalk would NOT normally exist b/c LL1 doesn't apply, because that's what non-intersection crosswalk means!

Comment: @Andy where you're going wrong is to assume that the presence of a marked crosswalk implies that there cannot also be an unmarked crosswalk. You tried to support that assumption with your "local example," but when I pointed out that your interpretation of that example is incorrect under Ohio law, you said that the example didn't apply to Ohio. Why then did you raise it? The plain meaning of LL(1) is that the entire area between projected property and curb lines is crosswalk. Putting a marking there under LL(2) could make the crosswalk bigger but not smaller.

Comment: @phoog Where you're going wrong is that you assume that a marked crosswalk does not override the boundaries which would apply if it were unmarked.  I did not try to support my correct assessment with just a local example, I also offered other logical reasons why that is the case, including language in the actual laws themselves which further re-enforces my stance.  The plain meaning of there being an LL1 and LL2 is that they are mutually exclusive.  It does not state anywhere in the law that the markings co-exist with the definition in LL1.

Comment: @phoog You've even acknowledge that the purpose of marking the crosswalks is to remove confusion as where the crosswalk is, yet you've not resolved that only partially marking a crosswalk defeats that purpose, especially when they could have just marked the entire crosswalk.  Where does the law allow a partially marked crosswalk even?  Instead you put your fingers in your ears and just assert that your nonsense interpretation is "reasonable," when it is not.  The courts aren't stupid, they are not going to conclude that allowing a partially marked crosswalk would make any kind of sense.

Comment: @Andy As the law is written, an LL2 crosswalk can only extend the boundaries of an LL1 crosswalk. There is nothing anywhere in the statutory text that suggests that LL1 and LL2 are mutually exclusive; there is no need for something to "state" that markings "co-exist"; you just have two definitions, and every point in the road that meets either definition is inside a crosswalk. I don't imagine that anyone would partially mark a crosswalk on purpose; such a crosswalk would be a fault of traffic engineering as shown by the Ohio MUTCD. It is certainly arguable that the law is poorly drafted, ...

Comment: ... but a poorly drafted law leads to an unintended result.  It is not the courts' duty to look through poor drafting and conjure up the supposed will of the legislature.  If the legislature wanted LL1 and LL2 to be mutually exclusive then it should have said so.  It didn't, so they aren't.

Comment: @phoog You're adding a limitation that doesn't exist.  Nothing suggests that LL2 cannot stand on its own, and it certainly is not limited to extending a crosswalk.  Indeed, if that were the case, nothing in the law allows for crosswalks not at intersections, which clearly are allowed.  And courts will take the most reasonable interpretation of the law, they won't just brain-dead follow your "logic."  And as I've said, the most reasonable thing is the definitions are mutually exclusive, because then there is never the possibility of partially marked crosswalks.

Comment: Your issue is that you are brain dead when interpreting the law; courts will not be so irrational.  I've given you arguments why the most reasonable interpretation is that they are mutually exclusive, the primary one is that the goal of marking is to remove confusion.  Your interpretation does the opposite, and for no benefit at all.  If the legislature wanted LL1 & LL2 to be a union of definitions, then it should have said so.  It didn't, so they aren't.

Comment: @Andy You are the one imputing a relationship between LL1 and LL2 by asserting that a marking within a portion of an LL1 crosswalk causes the LL1 definition of crosswalk to cease to apply at that intersection.  Rather, both sections *do* stand on their own, which is precisely why an unmarked and marked crosswalk may coexist if the markings do not fully encompass the unmarked crosswalk.  I did not mean to suggest that LL2 can only extend unmarked crosswalks; it can of course also create crosswalks away from intersections.  But it cannot reduce the extent of an unmarked crosswalk.

Comment: The thing is that courts *do* interpret laws with the sort of logic I'm employing in this discussion: it's called logical disjunction. If *either* proposition is true in a logical disjunction, the entire proposition is true. Thus, if some part of a road falls under LL1 then that part of the road is a crosswalk, regardless of how near or far away the nearest crosswalk marking may be, ten yards, ten feet, or ten inches.  Regarding the first sentence of your most recent comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/conduct

Answer (score -1):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

### Pedestrians always have right if way

Hit a pedestrian - go to jail. Unless it was impossible to avoid the collision such as a pedestrian suddenly stepping out within the car’s best stopping distance and assuming the driver was driving to the conditions (not doing 100 in a 50 zone).

The pedestrian can be booked but they still have right of way.

Comment: i was hit the other day when crossing. the walk signal was on, but i was crossing at an angle towards the crosswalk. the car bumped into me slowly so the driver would have seen me. was i wrong?

Comment: @confusedpanda1 the USA is weird - everywhere else it’s the driver’s responsibility to never hit a pedestrian

Comment: @DaleM that's true in the US, too.  Why would you think it isn't?

Comment: I wouldn’t say they have the right of way - but you are not allowed to drive into pedestrians whether they have the right of way or not.

Comment: This is wrong. A driver is obligated not to hit a pedestrian, but that does not always give them the right of way.  It may be that both parties are ruled at fault. And i think there are actually some states that have a "first one to break the law loses " law, but i don't know how that would affect things.   Certainly in my state there have been cases of drivers not being charged fir hitting a pedestrian because the pedestrian broke the law and there was no way for the driver to react in time.

Comment: You're confusing different concepts here.  In the state of Washington, for example, if I drive into a pedestrian who is in a crosswalk, I'm guilty of both vehicular assault and failure to yield the right-of-way.  If I drive into a pedestrian who is crossing away from a crosswalk, I'm guilty of vehicular assault, but the pedestrian is guilty of failure to yield the right-of-way.

Comment: @Mark as I said, only in the US do cars ever have right-of-way over pedestrians. In the rest of the world, there are circumstances where the pedestrian may be acting illegally but they still have the right-of-way.